# Azure ad add member from one group to another

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm looking to learn some powershell since not a lot of people in my organisation know a lot about coding. I just started using PS and it was a long time since i wrote any code whatsoever so I'm just trying to do a simple script that gets all the group members from one Azure AD group and adds them to another. Been looking around and taking bits from here and there and this is what i got so far.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $Credential


$group1 = "ObjectId pulled from AAD"
$group2 = "ObjectId pulled from AAD"

$membersGroup1 = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group1

foreach($member in $membersGroup1)
{
    $currentuser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member | select objectid
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group2 -RefObjectId $currentuser.objectid

}
Disconnect-AzureAD
```

The errors i am getting is:

> $currentuser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member | select obj ...
>   Add-AzureADGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter
>   'RefObjectId' because it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, you need to add `.ObjectId` in your command.

```
$currentuser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member.ObjectId | select objectid
```

Also you need to make sure the member in `$group1` is not in `$group2`, otherwise you will get a `One or more added object references already exist` error.

Comment: I did and the script worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. Do i close the question or somehow mark it as solved?
Regarding the thing about members being in both groups i expected that, just wanted to get it to work first. I figure i can add an if-statement to check if the $currentuser is part of $group2

Answer (score 0):

For groups with over 100 users:

```
$group1 = "ObjectId pulled from AAD"
$group2 = "ObjectId pulled from AAD"

$membersGroup1 = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group1 -All $true

foreach($member in $membersGroup1)
{
    $currentuser = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $member.ObjectId | select objectid
    Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group2 -RefObjectId $currentuser.objectid

}
```